# Page_init and Page_prerender methods - performance issues

Tags: asp.net

We were running a simple aspx page on IIS7.5 and we observed that it is taking long time to exit Page_Init method and call Page_PreRender method. There is nothing getting executed between these methods. See trace for the page calls.

```
[INFO   ] 2011-07-15 18:30:24,783 [6] Customer.Ektron.Web END - Page_Init() 
[INFO   ] 2011-07-15 18:30:27,486 [6] Customer.Ektron.Web START - Page_PreRender
```

Wondering if anyone has experienced this before.. This is simply killing our application performance..

Comment: Does the page inherit from another page (other than system.web.ui.page)?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the output of log4net, and not the default /trace.axd handler.

Between Init and PreRender comes the Load event which, *I believe*, is the default event for doing any work [in tutorials]. There are also other events, like InitComplete, PreLoad, and LoadComplete which executes, and there's state (viewstate and controlstate) loading if it is a postback, including raising any postback events.

Comment: yes this is the output of log4net..There are many events comes in between init and load but we are not using them. Our key issue is, we are not able to make out what is taking time in these two functions.

Comment: Look into the /trace.axd handler. You'll find timings for the other events there, which will help you further determining what event actually takes takes time.